Strange color pattern popping on when painting texture
I'm trying to paint a model which is already unwrapped and has a dds texture applied on it (it comes from a video game).
When I start painting on the model (or on the image texture), a strange pattern (see the picture) appears on some parts of the model. The pattern appears as soon as I click on it, even with a single point. It seems to appear on random vertices islands, even parts which are not painted.

Do you have a texture loaded as a brush texture by accident? Like this looks like what happens when you reference the same texture you are painting on as the brush.
